# running ruby on terminal gives me a different output than leetcode

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing leetcode and checking other people's solutions for the same exercise on my terminal gives a totally different output than expected. If I run it on leetcode it says the answer is correct...
What might be causing this?

reversing the array of chars - ["h","e","l","l","o"] -  like so:

```
def reverse_string(s)
   len = s.length
  (0...len/2).each { |i|
      temp = s[i]
      swap_index = len-i-1
      s[i] = s[swap_index]
      s[swap_index] = temp
  }
end

p reverse_string([["h","e","l","l","o"]])
```

output in my terminal -- 0...2

output in leetcode is as expected - ["o","l","l","e","h"]

Why does this happen?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's `p` function will print the value you pass to it.

The value you are choosing to pass to it is the return value of `reverse_string`.

You should add a line to the end of `reverse_string` that specifies what you want to return from it.  In this case the line can simply consist of `s`.  You don't even need an explict `return` in this case.